# How to prove ¬¬(A ∨ B) leads to ¬¬(B ∨ A)?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

Using laws of natural deduction, how can one prove that the single premise ¬¬(A ∨ B) leads to ¬¬(B ∨ A)?

I have tried solving the problem for some time but to no avail.

Comment: What exactly have you tried; where are you stuck?

Comment: Double negation-elimination, folowed by Disjunction-elimination, followed by Double negation-introduction.

Comment: (A or B) is the same as (B or A). After that, it doesn't matter what operations you apply to the result.

Comment: By the way, this is a theorem in intuitionistic logic. You don't need double negation elimination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proof in *Natural Deduction*, avoiding *Double negation*-elimination (thus, the derivation is intuitionistically *valid*) :

1) **¬¬(A ∨ B)** -- premise

2) **¬(B ∨ A)** --- assumed [a]

3) **A ∨ B** --- assumed [b]

4) **A** --- assumed [b1] for ∨-elimination

5) **B ∨ A** --- from 3) by ∨-introduction

6) **B** --- assumed [b2] for ∨-elimination

7) **B ∨ A** --- from 5) by ∨-introduction

8) **B ∨ A** --- from 3), 4)-5) and 6)-7) by ∨-elimination, discharging assumptions [b1] and [b2]

9) **⊥** --- from 2) and 8) by ¬-elimination

10) **¬(A ∨ B)** --- from 3) and 9) by ¬-introduction, discharging [b]

11) **⊥** --- from 1) and 10) by ¬-elimination

> 12) **¬¬(B ∨ A)** --- from 2) and 11) by ¬-introduction, discharging [a].

Answer (score 0):

The following proof used negation introduction (¬I) by assuming the negation of the conclusion represented as having one less negation connective.

To break the terms into simpler sentences, I used the DeMorgan Rule (DeM) to express the negation of a disjunction as a conjunction of negated sentences and then conjunction elimination (∧E) broke that into the component sentences. I recombined those sentences in the desired order using conjunction introduction (∧I).

Using the DeMorgan Rule again introduced a contradiction (⊥I) with the premise on line 1 which allowed me to introduce a negation (¬I) on line 9.

For more detailed information on these rules see *forall x: Calgary Remix*.

[image]

---

References

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/